# Problems with JQuery keypress in Bootstrap-Table: data-toggle="table"

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm using Bootstrap Table https://bootstrap-table.com/ 
I'm trying to validate inputs in my table, so I'm using JQuery keypress function.
But when I try to use keypress on inputs inside the table it doesn't work.
I tried many methods, but the only way was deleting: [data-toggle="table"] from my table, then keypress works again.
Do you know what can I do to use the keypress function when I'm using bootstrap table?
Here is my code:
(I'm using: https://bootstrap-table.com/ and JQuery)

```
<table id="table_1" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="input_1" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="input_2" type="text" />
            </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script>

$('#input_1').keypress(function() {
    alert('It works!');
});

$('#input_2').keypress(function() {
    alert('It works!');
});

</script>
```

Comment: I think what @MarkSkayff said its true, and i cant reproduce the same issue even when bootstrap script is added. If the solution that MarkSkayff gave did not solve the problem then please post all the script you have, that include script css etc. We need to see the problem to be able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions were right, as @MarkSkayff said it was a re-render problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be having an issue with the `<table>` being re-rendered by the Bootstrap-Table plugin.

Thus your events are getting lost.

To avoid this (in case this is the issue) you should use the following code:

```
$('#table_1).on("keypress", "#input_1", function(e) {
    alert('It works!');
});
```

And do the same with the other one. You can swap `#table_1` with something like `body` or `document` too and it might work.

Comment: As you said, I think it was a re-render problem with bootstrap-table, because using just: $('#input_1').keypress(function()... It works with elements that are not in the table. But using your solution it works with elements inside the bootstrap table. Thank you.

Comment: This is because when the plugin re-renders the table, the events are lost. The solution I've given you is an official solution from the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to assume to witohut seing your `.js`but here is an example.

Make sure you added `boostrap-table.css` and `boostrap-table.js` than:

Add this to your `.js` file:

```
$(function () {

  $('#table_1').bootstrapTable();

  $('#input_1').keypress(function() {
      alert('It works!');
  });

  $('#input_2').keypress(function() {
      alert('It works!');
  });

});
```

Here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/whatatimetobealive/3n7hurwy/17/).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. It seems like bootstrap-table have re-render issues, because when I use just: $('#input_1').keypress(function()... It works with elements that are not in table. But using your solution it works with elements inside the table. Thank you.